# Generate Computer Move

Tags: java

I've made a tic-tac-toe game and while I have a working computer move code, it just seems to go from left to right across the board instead of picking a random board slot.

Here's my code for the computer move:

```
public static void compTurn(char[][] board, char computer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == ' ')
            {
                board[i][j] = computer;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for generating a random move? Right now you have nested arrays going line by line.

Comment: I don't have a code for generating a random move.  All I have is code that moves the computer piece across the board unless the spot is filled.  I need some help with generating a random move.  Would it be easier if I uploaded the whole entire code? @Ryan

Comment: This smells of class assignment :) But a simple way: make an array of all the empty x,y slots then use arrayOfEmptySlots[rand() % arrayOfEmptySlots.length]. And the specifics you should probably figure out :)

Comment: If you show your code so far for generating a random move and then ask for specific help on how to solve a specific problem, you'll be more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: This can be done without using a while-loop to test whether a random spot has been taken. This entire program can be implemented with 1D array. But the problem is, I don't think you will understand my solution.

Comment: @user3437460 That's why I opted for the overly-simple solution ;)

Comment: @EvanBechtol You can still show him the efficient "no-while loop" solution though. I will probably upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing right now is going sequentially through the spaces and checking if they are open. If they are, the computer will move there. what you need to do instead is select a random spot until it finds one. Even better, you could keep a list of spots that are occupied in an array and attempt to move to a spot that is vacant.

Here is a basic solution, but in all honesty using the array is a much better way to go, both in terms of performance and elegance. You would basically create 2 arrays; one to contain occupied slots (that holds what player occupies that slot), another array to hold vacant spots (could be a simple boolean value to indicate spot is available for a move.). Each turn, check the vacant array for a space that is open, randomly, them move to it.

```
public static void compTurn(char[][] board, char computer)
{
    Random rand;
    boolean moved = false;

    /* If we haven't moved, look for a space to move to
       max = the highest space you have
       min = the lowest space you have
     */
    while (!moved) {
        int randomSpace = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        /* I leave this part for you to figure out */
        if(thisSpace == ' ')
        {
            //make the computer move to this space
            moved = true;
        }
    };

}
```

As this is very obviously an assignment, I left some blanks for you to fill in yourself, but this should be what you are looking for.